# Get Software package extention from OS using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, platform

I am new to python. I am writing a python code to get to installable extention of the OS. For example, for Ubuntu OS, the Software package extention was .deb (debian) and for Windows OS, the Software package extenstion was .exe (executable). I want to get the extention via python code. I tried platform, OS modules but can't find a solution. How can I make that possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it in both the ways using os or pathlib module..

```
import os
import pathlib

file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext('python-3.7.2-macosx10.9.pkg')
file_ext
--> '.pkg'

pathlib.PurePosixPath('python-3.7.2-macosx10.9.pkg').suffix
-->'.pkg'
```